# How to construct SSIS expression?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to use derived column in SQL BDS and in the derived column I want to do as follows:

1) If source column contains NULL, then replace it with "Unknown"

2) If there is a value, then replace it with the given string.

So far, I came up with this, but I`m unfamiliar with syntax for those expressions and I keep getting errors:

```
ISNULL(Source) ? "Unknown" :  REPLACE("m", "m", "Pop memories" ), REPLACE("h", "h", "Pop     hits" ), REPLACE("a", "a", "Pop annual" ), REPLACE("y", "y", "Yearbook" ), REPLACE("bs", "bs", "Bestsellers" )
```

I'm pretty sure the problem lies with commas between each replace, but I don`t know what else to use. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Okay, I solved it. Apperently you have to nest REPLACES for them to work like that:

```
ISNULL(Source) ? "Unknown" :  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Source, "bs", "Bestsellers" ), "m", "Pop memories" ), "h", "Pop     hits" ) , "a", "Pop annual" ), "y", "Yearbook" )
```

Comment: WHAT errors?  We're not psychic ;)

Comment: Invalid expression errors of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using a static expression like that.  Your problem with that is that if you have additional cases, you have to find and modify an increasingly complex expression statement.

A lookup transformation with a table that matches the source code with the description would be a better solution here.  You could set the lookup to ignore nulls and then include a simple expression in a derived column transformation like the following:

```
ISNULL(Description)?"Unknown":Description
```

That way, if you have new source codes, you can just add them to the lookup table and not have to change any code.